# Парсинг данных не обновляя страницу

Tags: парсер, xmlparser, web-scraping

необходимо сделать так что бы на странице происходил автоматический парсинг данных(не всех, а только нескольких блоков, в которых собственно и обновляется информация) но обновлять страницу нельзя.

возможно ли как то это реализовать?

Comment: Если информация обновляется только на части страницы, значит там происходит ajax вызов, который эти данные подгружает. Смотрите как он загружает данные, сами вызываете их загрузку и разбираете

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проблема в том что необходимые мне данные появляются и обновляются только если я остаюсь на странице, то есть, если я не буду присутствовать на n странице то у меня не появится блок с инфой вообще

поэтому возможно ли как то смоделировать бота, который бы просто присутствовал на n странице нонстоп, и выгружал мне динамическую информацию

то есть бот сам ничего не обновляет, данные к нему сами приходят по пути сервер-клиент(бот)

извиняюсь если пишу околесицу, на данный момент не обладаю достаточными знаниями

Comment: данные на страницу без перегрузки могут попадать 2 способами: 1. ajax вызов через определенные промежутки времени (по setTimeout) 2. webscoket подключение, через которое сервер передает данные по мере их появления. И да, можно сделать бота, который периодически сам вызывает загрузку, которую обычно делает ajax, так и бота читающего websocket. причем первый вариант распространен больше и с точки зрения бота ничем не отличается от загрузки страницы, просто он загружает периодически не url страницы, а url, который дергает ajax метод.

Comment: В любом случае начинать надо с изучения кода, который  меняет блоки на странице, что бы реализовать его аналогию в своем боте

Comment: Благодарю за то что уделил время и помог

Comment: Да, еще, думаю можно начать с того, что открыть интересующую страницу в хроме, зайти в меню->дополнительные инструменты->инструменты разработчика. Там переключиться на вкладку network. В ней видно все обращения к серверу, если это ajax то там будут появляться периодические запросы и нажав на них можно получить детальную информацию, что запрашивалось и что приходит в ответ